# .Include() affects query's number of results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have very simple query which returns `Order`, but when I perform the same query with many `Includes` and `ThenInclude` then query returns 0 results instead of 1

```
var a = _context
        .Orders
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == OrderId);

var b = _context
        .Orders
        .OrdersFullInclude()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == OrderId);
```

Where `OrdersFullInclude()` =

```
public static IQueryable<Order> OrdersFullInclude(this IQueryable<Order> input)
{
    return  input
           .Include(x => x.StatusesHistory)
           .Include(x => x.File)
           .Include(x => x.SomeData)
           .ThenInclude(x => x.SomeDeeperLevel)
           .Include(x => x.Company)
           .Include(x => x.Customer)
           .Include(x => x.Insurance)
           .ThenInclude(x => x.InsuranceSomething); 
}
```

Why?

Comment: Including *reference* navigation property generates `JOIN` in the query. The `JOIN` is either `INNER` (for required relationship) or `LEFT OUTER` (for optional relationship). So check the generated SQL - any `INNER JOIN` *can filter* the result. Most likely you have mapped some relationship as required while in the database it's not.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh, I thought it's gonna be just null. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By calling `Include` you are joining your result with some other tables, and seemingly not all the joined tables have a related record to the record in the first result set, therefore it's returning no result.